# can we convert flv to mp4 directly from internet using ffmpeg

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg, mp4, flv

**VB.Net**

This works fine for me

```
"-i ""C:\myfile.flv"" -ar 22050 FileName.mp4"
```

but can i use this one i.e.

```
"-i ""http://www.example.com/myfile.flv"" -ar 22050 FileName.mp4"
```

Comment: I have done this but when download reaches

flv @ 00946FE4]skipping flv packet: type 68, size 6386789, flags 0 

then it repeats this error

[flv @ 00946FE4]skipping flv packet: type 68, size 6386789, flags 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC19):

> The protocol http: is currently used only to communicate with FFserver (see the FFserver documentation). When FFmpeg will be a video player it will also be used for streaming :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you pull the file via http and write it to disk before trying to transcode it. This will also prevent having fragmented encodings should something go wrong when consuming it via ffmpeg.